# passing argument 1 of ‘function_name’ makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: c, function, parameters, declaration

So here's code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void draw(int length, char brush);
int stringLength(char name[]);
void drawName(char nameLetter[], char brush);

int length;
char brush, name;
char *a = "Anne", *b = "Bart", *c = "Celine", *d = "Darius";

int main(void) {
  printf("Write down the length of line.\n");
  scanf("%d", &length);
  printf("Give first letter of the name (a, b, c albo d)\n");
  scanf(" %c", &name);
  printf("Pick character to be used as brush.\n");
  scanf(" %c", &brush);
  drawName(name, brush);
  return 0;
}

void draw(int length, char brush) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    printf("%c", brush);
  }
}

int stringLength(char name[]) {
  int i;
  while (name[i] != '\0') {
    i++;
  }
  return i;
}

void drawName(char nameLetter[], char brush) {
  draw(stringLength(nameLetter), brush);
  printf("%s\n", nameLetter);
  draw(stringLength(nameLetter), brush);
}
```

What I'm trying to do here, is to get the length of a string and use this value as a parameter in another function responsible for printing as many characters in a row, as there are characters is in given string. But I get an error at line 19: (passing argument 1 of ‘drawName’ makes pointer from integer without a cast).. I've read all the questions simiar to this one here on stackoverflow, but still can't make it work. I'd appreciate your help a lot! I'm at a dead end here...

Comment: `drawName` takes a `char *` as its parameter (decayed from `char []`). Your code is clearly passing a single `char` parameter instead. What is there not to understand, about this?

Comment: In `stringLength()` you fail to initialise `i`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function

```
void drawName(char nameLetter[], char brush);
```

is declared with the first parameter of type `char *`

While you are calling it with an argument of type `char`.

```
char brush, name;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//...            
drawName(name, brush);
```

Comment: Whenever I change char name to char * name I get an error: (format ‘%c’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char **’)

Comment: @angrysomoan If you want to enter a string you have to declare name as a character array and use at least format specifier %s or you can use standard function fgetsinstead of scanf.

Comment: Im trying to get an character, and use that to point to string name (for example: get char a, and use that as parameter in function to point to string variable named a). How to do that?

Comment: @angrysomoan It is impossible.

Comment: _Im trying to get an character, and use that to point to string name (for example: get char a, and use that as parameter in function to point to string variable named a)._ This is completly weird. You may have an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).